# MVC Webapi get method passing model as parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model, asp.net-web-api

I am using mvc4 webapi, I want to know how to make ajax call that passes a model as the  parameter to a Get Method. I am getting model null on Get method.

```
//Controller

public HttpResponseMessage GetUsersList(ProfileModel objProfileModel)
{
}

//Jquery Ajax

function GetUsersList()
{
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/SearchWebApi/GetUsersList',
    data: $("#frmsearch").serialize(),
    success: function (data)
    {


    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        //window.location = JsErrorAction;
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there are a few problems with what you are doing. Try these changes:

1) Change your ajax call to a `GET` rather than a `POST`

```
$.ajax({type: 'GET', ...
```

**OR** change your action name to `Post(ProfileModel objProfileModel)` but I think a get in this case is more RESTful as you are doing a search.

2) Don't put your action as part of your url. web-api route conventions use the http verb to determine which action to use. So, if you controller is called `SearchWebApi`, your url would just be this:

```
url: '/api/SearchWebApi/'
```

The routing engine will figure out that the get will go to the method/action with `get` in the name.

3) Having your form data in the body should be okay. But be aware that you may need to explicitly say this by marking your parameter:

```
GetUsersList([FromBody] ProfileModel objProfileModel)
```

**EDIT:**

To address your question about multiple get methods, I guess there are a couple of options.

The 'convention' in Web Api is that you would have a separate controller for each resource. So you would have an Image controller and a separate Users controller. Thus no conflict and urls still make sense:

```
GET /api/images/
GET /api/users/
```

You can have multiple Get methods on a controller but they can't conflict. So you'll see a lot of Controllers for a resource that have a Get which returns a collection, and a get which is by id to get a specific resource.

public HttpResponseMessage Get()

public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)

But really, it all comes down to how you want to specify your API, and how you define the routes. The **default** api route is this:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Notice that this doesn't specify an action. If you wanted to allow multiple gets on the same controller you could just add an `{action}` segment to the url, just like regular Mvc.

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Hi, Your answer solved my issue, one question is that according 2) point as you have mentioned...why no need to pass method name in URL? for example if i have 2 methods(a) GetUsersList, b) GetImages) in WebApi controller, with fetching the data then which one will be called without passing method name in URL

Comment: @user2734405 I've added an update to my answer to address your question